# cloudbees imagemagick resize does not works

Tags: grails, jenkins, imagemagick, cloudbees

I'm trying to deploy a grails application on cloudbees.
In order to do that, I have a Jenkins job that builds the war and it deploy it.
My application uses ImageMagick in order to resize pictures.
After reading on cloudbees site that their servers have already ImageMagick installed, I did a test:
In my Jenkiks job a have a "execute shell" part where I put :

```
convert --version
```

When running the job, everything works fine and I see on the console output:

```
+ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.5-6 2012-08-11 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

My application uses im4java wrapper.
When I try to resize a picture in my application I have the following error:

```
org.im4java.core.CommandException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "convert": error=2, No such file or directory
```

So, I don't understant why does not works since ImageMagick is installed.

Can you please give me some idea ?

Thanks.

C.C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem here is that ImageMagick is installed as a build tool on the development environment (DEV@cloud) but not on the stack you are using for the runtime environment (RUN@cloud). I cannot see any ImageMagick dependency added into the [Tomcat 6-7 stack](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat-clickstack).

Only way to have imagemagick on runtime is to create a specific new stack which makes it available for you. So need to fork the git repo and use [genapp](https://github.com/cloudbees/genapp) as a development tool for the new stack.

Comment: I was just reading again the phrase and I think you are right.

Comment: Using cloudbees SDK is it possible to install it ?

Comment: Just update the answer to provide more information. Sorry, but on runtime users don't usually need these kind of tools.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks. I used to work directly on Amazon Web Services and manipulating the cloud formation files. If I understand corectely, the cloud bees stack is the same thing.